# Symfony 4.3 - Cannot autowire service argument in nested inheritance

Tags: symfony, autowired

I have 3 services and 1 controller. The problem is that the grandpa service has a problem to autowire its constructor argument.

- `RegistrationController` has action that has`RegisterDB` service as argument.
- `RegisterDB` extends `DBALProvider` service.
- `DBALProvider` extends `BaseService` service.
- `DBALProvider` has constructor that autowires some arguments and saves them to properties that are returned by getters.
- `BaseService` has constructor that **does not** autowire argument so its property is null (**not null expected**).

Bare minimum code:

**RegistrationController.php**

```
 class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
    {
      public function register(RegisterDB $registerDB)
      {
        $registerDB->registerUser();die;
      }
    }
```

**RegisterDB.php**

```
class RegisterDB extends DBALProvider
{
  public function registerUser()
  {
    dump($this->getTranslator());
    dump($this->getContext());
  }
}
```

**DBALProvider.php**

```
class DBALProvider extends BaseService
{
  private $context;

  public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
  {
    $this->context = $entityManager->getConnection();
  }

  protected function getContext()
  {
    return $this->context;
  }
}
```

**BaseService.php**

```
class BaseService
{
  private $translator;

  public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
  {
    $this->translator = $translator;
  }

  protected function getTranslator()
  {
    return $this->translator;
  }
}
```

The problem is that in RegisterDB.php 1st dump `dump($this->getTranslator());` outputs `null` but 2nd dump shows expected connection object. What's wrong with my inheritance chain?

Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with autowiring, but with how inheritance works.

Since your `BaseService` expects an instance of `TranslatorInterface` you need to pass it to the parent constructor in your `DBALProvider` class:

```
class DBALProvider extends BaseService
{
  private $context;

  public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, TranslatorInterface $translator)
  {
    $this->context = $entityManager->getConnection();
    parent::__construct($translator);
  }

  protected function getContext()
  {
    return $this->context;
  }
}
```

Comment: Right, but if you remove constructor from `DBALProvider` the first dump will output translator object which is kinda confusing.

`DBALProvider` constructor also expects EntityManagerInterface but `RegisterDB` has no constructor (that's why `DBALProvider`s constructor is executed)... What is strange to me is that constructor from parent class is executed even when there is no constructor in child class.

Comment: Think about how annoying it would be if every time you extended a class you also had to add a constructor and then explicitly call any parent constructor.  In any event, that is just the way php works.

Comment: Wait... It seems like it has something to do with Symfony.
If you have `class B extends A` and class A has constructor and class B has not then you must provide all arguments from class A constructor when you create B object. So when Symfony tries to create `RegisterDB` object it somehow pass necessary argument for `DBALProvider` constructor like this: 
`$symfonyStuff = new RegisterDB(new EntityManagerInterface ())`.
Any deeper inheritence is as you explained: you need to pass argument for parent constructor.